# Passing Restart job arguments while submitting Dataproc job using DataprocSubmitJobOperator

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-dataproc

I need to run Spark streaming job in Google Dataproc Cluster using Airflow. I learnt that Dataproc jobs can be automatically restarted incase of failures by optional settings as shown [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/jobs/restartable-jobs#gcloud). And it properly works if submit the job through GCP console.

However I don't know where to include the argument `max-failures-per-hour` while submitting the Dataproc job through Airflow's `DataprocSubmitJobOperator`.

Here is the Airflow DAG code,

```
spark_submit_properties = {
    'spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled': 'true',
    # ...
}

job_args = {
    "gcs_job": {
        "args": [--],
        "jar_file_uris": [f"--"],
        "main_class": "---",
        "properties": spark_submit_properties
    }
}

submit_job = {
    "reference": {"project_id": v_project_id},
    "placement": {"cluster_name": v_cluster_name},
    "spark_job": job_args["gcs_job"]
}


spark_job_submit = DataprocSubmitJobOperator(
        task_id="XXXX",
        job=submit_job,
        location="us-central1",
        gcp_conn_id=v_conn_id,
        project_id=v_project_id
    )
```

I am not even sure if `max_failures_per_hour` or `max-failures-per-hour` is the proper argument name to pass to `DataprocSubmitJobOperator`.

If I add them to `job_args` in above code I get the error,

```
Exception:
Protocol message SparkJob has no "max_failures_per_hour" field.
```

And if I directly add `max_failures_per_hour = 1` to `DataprocSubmitJobOperator()` I am getting DAG import error stating `max_failures_per_hour` is an invalid argument.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. You can add it under `"scheduling"` config as below,

```
submit_job = {
    "reference": {"project_id": v_project_id},
    "placement": {"cluster_name": v_cluster_name},
    "scheduling": {"max_failures_per_hour": 5},
    "spark_job": job_args["gcs_job"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no parameter `max_failures_per_hour` in Airflow's [`DataprocSubmitJobOperator`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/operators/cloud/dataproc.html#submit-a-job-to-a-cluster).

As you have mentioned, using the console you will be able to pass the parameter `max-failures-per-hour`,
when submitting [Dataproc job](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/jobs/restartable-jobs#gcloud).

For example using gcloud command:

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit job type \
    --region=region \
    --max-failures-per-hour=number
```

Maximum number of times a job can be restarted per hour is 10.

Comment: Actually you can. Answer posted.